# I need help to fix the damage done to my computer with Restoro

Tags: windows, windows-10

It seems Restoro has damaged the pathways and directories to my computer. My user.config XML file seems to be damaged because of it. When I use my search function on my computer, it doesn't bring up the bluetooth options in the search despite the fact that bluetooth works on my computer and I activate it through the settings. Similarly, when searching Control Panel, despite appearing, pressing open doesn't start Control Panel up, I have to manually open it up from my settings. There's also the fact that when I start up my computer, I get an error with these details:

```
`See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Failed to save settings: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Unable to open file 'C:\Users\natha\AppData\Local\MSI\SCM.exe_Url_zv0ikcohnhzptbjtykvepncdk0ijftla\13.17.11141.0\user.config' for writing because it is read-only or hidden. (C:\Users\natha\AppData\Local\MSI\SCM.exe_Url_zv0ikcohnhzptbjtykvepncdk0ijftla\13.17.11141.0\user.config) ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Unable to open file 'C:\Users\natha\AppData\Local\MSI\SCM.exe_Url_zv0ikcohnhzptbjtykvepncdk0ijftla\13.17.11141.0\user.config' for writing because it is read-only or hidden. (C:\Users\natha\AppData\Local\MSI\SCM.exe_Url_zv0ikcohnhzptbjtykvepncdk0ijftla\13.17.11141.0\user.config) ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to open file 'C:\Users\natha\AppData\Local\MSI\SCM.exe_Url_zv0ikcohnhzptbjtykvepncdk0ijftla\13.17.11141.0\user.config' for writing because it is read-only or hidden.
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.StaticOpenStreamForWrite(String streamName, String templateStreamName, Object& writeContext, Boolean assertPermissions)
   at System.Configuration.ClientSettingsStore.ClientSettingsConfigurationHost.OpenStreamForWrite(String streamName, String templateStreamName, Object& writeContext)
   at System.Configuration.MgmtConfigurationRecord.SaveAs(String filename, ConfigurationSaveMode saveMode, Boolean forceUpdateAll)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Configuration.MgmtConfigurationRecord.SaveAs(String filename, ConfigurationSaveMode saveMode, Boolean forceUpdateAll)
   at System.Configuration.ClientSettingsStore.WriteSettings(String sectionName, Boolean isRoaming, IDictionary newSettings)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Configuration.ClientSettingsStore.WriteSettings(String sectionName, Boolean isRoaming, IDictionary newSettings)
   at System.Configuration.LocalFileSettingsProvider.SetPropertyValues(SettingsContext context, SettingsPropertyValueCollection values)
   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.SaveCore()
   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.Save()
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Save()
   at MSI.SCM.SCMII.SetECOtoEC()
   at MSI.SCM.SCMII.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4614.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
SCM
    Assembly Version: 13.17.11141.0
    Win32 Version: 13.017.11141.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/SCM/SCM.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4190.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4605.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4605.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4550.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4390.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
WPFOSD
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/SCM/WPFOSD.DLL
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4605.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationFramework.dll
----------------------------------------
WindowsBase
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4605.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/WindowsBase/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/WindowsBase.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationCore
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4605.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/PresentationCore/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationCore.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xaml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4605.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xaml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xaml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Management
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4435.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Management/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Management.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework.Aero2
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework.Aero2/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll
----------------------------------------
UIAutomationTypes
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4605.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/UIAutomationTypes/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/UIAutomationTypes.dll
----------------------------------------
UIAutomationProvider
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4605.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/UIAutomationProvider/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/UIAutomationProvider.dll
----------------------------------------
MSIECO
    Assembly Version: 1.0.1308.2003
    Win32 Version: 1.0.1308.2003
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/SCM/MSIECO.DLL
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.`
```

I tried using Control Panel to fix it and looked up solutions on the web but there doesn't seem to be any solutions to Restoro's meddling. I'm wondering if I should wipe my computer.

Comment: How good is your backup strategy? Avoid this kind of snake oil like the plague.

Comment: If System Restore is enabled, rollback to before you ran this abomination.

Comment: Suggestion for the future: make *drive images* on a regular basis. Then, when there's an issue, you can return to *exactly* the state of the last image. There are a  number of trustworthy imaging tools, such as Macrium Reflect and alternatives: https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/ . And don't trust a tool blindly, check VirusTotal.org and reviews.

Comment: If we go by reviews, both [Techradar Pro](https://www.techradar.com/reviews/restoro) and [Windows Report](https://windowsreport.com/restoro-review/) give Restoro quite a glowing reviews, and at least Windows Report gets a top Trustpilot score...

Comment: Should I just upload all my files to onedrive and reset my computer?

Answer (score 2):

This is supposed to be a Registry Repair App.

[Restoro](https://www.restoro.com/pages/lwdu/index.php?tracking=GGRes&banner=1&adgroup=direct&ads_name=direct&keyword=1&dyn_param=Restoro:_Total_Repair_and_Protection&lpx=lwdu&&whf=true&banner=1502202175&adgroup=58615322140&keyword=restoro%20exe&ads_name=&gclid=Cj0KCQjwz6ShBhCMARIsAH9A0qXmU8v1seop3Ddwv8ZNuP1TyZCzLCT9yqnq_lYW89_LcNnnzyA90AEaAlySEALw_wcB)

However, numerous Registry Repair apps are not professional registry tools at all.

Best advice, since the registry is likely hosed, is to back up what you can and re-install Windows.

Comment: Should I just backup all my files and reset the computer?

Comment: Yes, this is what you should do. Backing out registry errors is near impossible.